# How can I make this faster at reading and writing?

Tags: java, performance, stream, text-processing, bigdata

```
public class DataMiner  {

private static BigData app = new BigData();
private static DomainOfConstants doc = new DomainOfConstants();
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataMiner.class);
private static DBManager conn = new DBManager();
private static java.sql.Connection con = null;
private static AmazonS3  s3Client;
private static Iterator<String> itr;
private static List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
private static S3Object s3Object;
private static ObjectMetadata meta;
public static InputStream dataStream;
public static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
public static File file = new File(app.getCurrentPacsId()+".txt");



private static void obtainConnection(){
    conn.connection();
    entries = conn.grabDataSet();       
    conn.closeDb();
    downloadBucket();
}

/*
 * 
 * The Java heap size limits for Windows are:
 * maximum possible heap size on 32-bit Java: 1.8 GB
 * recommended heap size limit on 32-bit Java: 1.5 GB (or 1.8 GB with /3GB option)
 * 
 * */
/*-------------Download and un-zip backup file-------------*/
private static void downloadBucket(){

    try {
        app.setAwsCredentials(doc.getAccessKey(), doc.getSecretKey());
        s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(app.getAwsCredentials())).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
        System.out.println("Connected to S3");
        itr = entries.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            app.setBucketKey(itr.next());
            String key = app.getBucketKey();
            app.setCurrentPacsId(key);
            s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(doc.getDesiredBucket(), app.getBucketKey()));
            try {
                ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent());
                ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
                extractObjects(buffer, s3Client, zis, entry);                   
            } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                log.error(e);
            } catch (SdkClientException e) {
                log.error(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Processing complete");


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public static void extractObjects(byte[] buffer, AmazonS3 s3Client, ZipInputStream zis, ZipEntry entry) throws IOException {
    PipedOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PipedInputStream is = null;
    try {
        while (entry != null) 
        {
            String fileName = entry.getName();
            if (fileName == "lib") {
                fileName = entry.getName();
            }
            boolean containsBackup = fileName.contains(doc.getDesiredFile());

            if (containsBackup == true) {
                System.out.println("A back up file was found");
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                formatSchemaName();
                System.out.println("Extracting :" + app.getCurrentPacsId());
                log.info("Extracting " + app.getCurrentPacsId() + ", 
                compressed: " + entry.getCompressedSize() + " bytes, 
                extracted: " + 
                entry.getSize() + " bytes");
         //ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                outputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
                is = new PipedInputStream(outputStream);

                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) >= 0) 
                {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
   //InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
                meta = new ObjectMetadata();
                meta.setContentLength(file.length());
                fileName = app.getCurrentPacsId();
                runDataConversion(is,s3Client,fileName);
                recordTime(start);
                is.close();
                outputStream.close();
                System.out.println("Unzip complete");               
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("No back up found");
            }
            entry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (SdkClientException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}


/*------------Formating the replacment file name---------*/
private static void formatSchemaName(){
    String s3Key = app.getCurrentPacsId();
    String id = s3Key.replace(".zip", ".txt");
    id = id.substring(id.indexOf("_"));
    id = id.replaceFirst("_", "");
    app.setCurrentPacsId(id);
}

/*---------------Process the data file----------------------*/
private static void runDataConversion(PipedInputStream is, AmazonS3 s3Client, String fileName) {
    DataProcessor convert = new DataProcessor(s3Client);
    convert.downloadBucket(is,fileName);
}

/*-------Records execution time of program in min/sec------*/
private static void recordTime(long start) throws IOException {
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(end - start);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(end - start);
    System.out.println("Execution speed "+ minutes + ":" + (seconds % 60) +" min/sec\n");
}
```

And here is the class that does some text file processing.The code is very slow overall when processing files up to 3.5gb. It takes 3 hours to do so while running. I have tried using piped streams over byte streams. Java heap size set to -xms2800m on a 64 bit JDK.

```
public class DataProcessor {

private static AmazonS3 s3Client;
private static ObjectMetadata meta;
private static DomainOfConstants doc = new DomainOfConstants();
private static BigData app = new BigData();
public static File file = new File(app.getCurrentPacsId()+".txt");
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataProcessor.class);

//Construct connection
public DataProcessor (AmazonS3 s3Client){
    this.s3Client = s3Client;
}

//
public void downloadBucket(PipedInputStream is, String fileName) {
    try {
        File dataStream = dataConversion(is);
        s3Client.putObject(doc.getDestinationBucket(),FilenameUtils.getFullPath(doc.getDestinationKey()) + "Modified_"+ fileName, dataStream);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e);
    } catch (SdkClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e);

    }               
}

//Setup reading and writing streams
public static File dataConversion(PipedInputStream stream) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedOutputStream streamOut = null;
    String line;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,doc.getFileFormat()));
        streamOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        meta = new ObjectMetadata();
        while(( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
        {
            processLine(reader, streamOut, line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            streamOut.close();
            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
    return file;
}


/*---------------------------------------Data processing------------------------------------------------*/

    /*-----------Process and print lines---------*/
private static void processLine(BufferedReader reader, BufferedOutputStream streamOut, String line) {
    try {
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while (reader.ready()) {
            if (line.contains(doc.getInsert())) {
                handleData(streamOut, line);
            } else if (line.contains(doc.getUse())) {
                handleSchemaName(streamOut, line);
            } else {
                streamOut.write(line.toLowerCase().getBytes(Charset.forName(doc.getFileFormat()).toString()));
                streamOut.write(newLine.getBytes());
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e);

    }
}

    /*-----------Replace-Schema-Name-----------*/
private static void handleSchemaName(BufferedOutputStream streamOut, String line) throws IOException {
    line = line.replace(line, "USE " + "`" + doc.getSchemaName() + app.getCurrentPacsId() + "`;");
    streamOut.write(line.getBytes(Charset.forName(doc.getFileFormat())));
}


    /*--------Avoid-Formating-Data-Portion-of-file--------*/
private static void handleData(BufferedOutputStream streamOut, String line) throws IOException {
    StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tk.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String data = tk.nextToken();
        if (data.equals(doc.getValue())) {
            streamOut.write(data.toLowerCase().getBytes(Charset.forName(doc.getFileFormat()).toString()));
            data = tk.nextToken();
            while (tk.hasMoreTokens()) {
                streamOut.write(data.getBytes(Charset.forName(doc.getFileFormat())));
                data = tk.nextToken();
            }
        }
        streamOut.write(line.toLowerCase().getBytes(Charset.forName(doc.getFileFormat().toString())));
        streamOut.write(" ".getBytes(Charset.forName(doc.getFileFormat())));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try some judicious System.out.println statements to try to identify the slow areas of your code. you may be able to introduce a `break;` in one of your loops if a condition is met so you won't have to keep processing the data. If that doesn't narrow it down, then try using a java profiler.

Comment: Have you tried to profile it? You need to find out where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Yes I am using VisualVM to profile it. I also found with print statements that the code is very fast up to the point of the actual data conversion, reading the input stream, processing it. What kind program running time should I expect to read a 3.5gb file, process some text and write it to a new file?

Answer (score 2):

1. Rule 1 is always to use a bigger buffer. 1024 is pitifully small. Try 32-64K.
2. You need to start the pipe reading thread *before* doing any writes to the pipe. In fact I'm surprised you don't get 'read end dead' errors. Does this code really work at all?
3. In fact get rid of the piped streams. Use a single thread and do all the processing as you go.
4. Get rid of the `ready()` test. It is an extra system call for nothing. Just read until end of stream.
5. Use a `BufferedWriter` instead of a `BufferedOutputStream` and stop converting all those strings to bytes (and use `BufferedWriter.newLine()` instead of the system property).

Comment: All I did was increase the buffer to the recommended 32k and the program just increased 5x in speed! I forgot I had that set so small for testing the small files. I will have to look into using bufferedwritter, I had been writing to streams previously. This was because the AWS PUTobject required a input stream as a parameter.

Comment: If Increase my buffer to 64k will this lead to issues in processing the larger files of 4gb? Will I have heap issues at xms3000m?

Comment: How? 64K is 64K. It doesn't have anything to do with the size of the file. But don't expect it to go twice as fast with 64K as 32K. The benefits are asymptotic. Most of the 5x came from going from 1K to 8K.

Comment: With the above mentioned using a 64k buffer and a 2800mb initial heap in run time configurations. I have managed to get program run time down to 2.5 hours to process a 3.4gb text file. It was at 3.5 hours before hand.

Comment: You could also try a `BufferedInputStream` under the `ZipInputStream`, but there may be one already there so it may not make a difference. Final piece of advice: don't flush in write loops. I don't get the nested `readLine()` loops: the outer one will only execute once.